# Searching - from index view and result to another view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, search, razor

i'm creating a search function in mvc5
my program works like this:
Index view have search box and button
and the result of that also displays in index view

so my problem is that how do i display the result in another view - say like searchresult.cshtml and not in index view?

here's my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string searching)
{
 return View(db.TblId.Where(x => x.IdNumber.Contains(searching) || searching == null));
}
```

my index view (i just removed the other text contents, only included the search result)

```
@model IEnumerable<MVC5_Search.Models.TblId>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.TextBox("searching")<input type="submit" value="Search" />
}

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Id Number</td>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>Middle Name</td>
            <td>Last Name</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (Model.Count() == 0)
        {
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="color: red">
                    No Result!
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.IdNumber</td>
                    <td>@item.Firstname</td>
                    <td>@item.Middlename</td>
                    <td>@item.Lastname</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

i'm using this together with entity framework

EDIT:(trying to solve)

here's what i've done so far,

i created another controller (SearchingController) to avoid conflict with the main controller,

```html
[HttpGet]
        public ViewResult SearchResult(string searching)
        {
            return View("SearchResult", db.TblId.Where(x => x.TId.Contains(searching) || searching == null));
        }
```

and then the view SearchResult.cshtml

```html
@model IEnumerable<TblId.Models.TId>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "searchresult";
}

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>IdNumber</td>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>Middle Name</td>
            <td>Last Name</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (Model.Count() == 0)
        {
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="color: red">
                    No Result!
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.IdNumber</td>
                    <td>@item.Firstname</td>
                    <td>@item.Middlename</td>
                    <td>@item.Lastname</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and in my index view,

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchResult", "Searching", FormMethod.Get))
                            {
                                @*@Html.TextBox("searching")*@
                                <input type="text" id="searching" name="searching" />

                                <button type="submit" name="searching" id="searching "class="btn btn-secondary">
                                    Verify
                                    <br>
                                </button>
                            }
```

still not working as expected

when i clicked search button, it just change the url to something like this

/Index?searching=T101&searching=

T101 - is the Id i'm searching

Comment: In your entire post there is no question mark (?).  What is your question?

Comment: Your `<form>` makes a GET back to you `Index()` method. If you want to display a different view, make a GET back to a different method that displays your `searchresult.cshtml` view (although its not clear why you would want to do that)

Comment: because index is index,i mean it is solely for home contents and not anything. i just want to give a user a clear view of the result. so when he/she search, he'she should just see the result and not anything else in the screen so as to avoid confusion.

Comment: create an ajax call to search and then return partial view from controller, on index view create div and pass partial view to the particular view,

Comment: will the result display in another view instead of index? i'm not sure how partial views work. would you give an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

-> Create a new view searchresult.cshtml with below contents

```
@model IEnumerable<MVC5_Search.Models.TblId>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Id Number</td>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>Middle Name</td>
            <td>Last Name</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (Model.Count() == 0)
        {
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="color: red">
                    No Result!
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.IdNumber</td>
                    <td>@item.Firstname</td>
                    <td>@item.Middlename</td>
                    <td>@item.Lastname</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

-> Modify your index post action to

```
[HttpPost]    
public ViewResult Index(string searching)
    {
     return View("searchresult",db.TblId.Where(x => x.IdNumber.Contains(searching) || searching == null));
    }
```

Comment: doesn't work as expected. what happens is that, the index only displays the table like result but without the data and the no result! message. all the contents of the index is not display aside from the table result

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean! Did you wanted to display the no result message in the index view and display SearchResult page only when you have data to display?

Comment: no. the no result! message will only display only if the user search the id which cannot be found in the database. and the results will be displayed in the searchresult view. i've edited my main post.

Comment: If your new Controller is SearchingController, then in the BeginForm what is Verification? It should be Searching!

Comment: yea it is searching, my bad..typo

Comment: @silver01, if it solves your problem, don't miss to accept the answer. :)